# 音の再生を重複したくない

Tags: javascript, html5

ボタン（画像）を押すと音が鳴り、再度押すと止まるサイトを作成中なのですが、再生とストップは出来たのですが、複数ボタンを設置すると、「ボタン1」を再生中に「ボタン2」を押すと1.mp3の音楽再生したまま、2.mp3が再生されてしまいます。
「ボタン2」のボタンを押したら1.mp3は止まるようにしたいのですが、教えて頂けますでしょうか？

**HTML**

```html
<span class="soundBtn1 clicked1">再生・停止</span>
<audio id="overSound1" preload="auto">
<source src="1.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  ※お使いの環境では再生できません。
</audio>
<span class="soundBtn2 clicked2">再生・停止</span>
<audio id="overSound2" preload="auto">
<source src="2.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  ※お使いの環境では再生できません。
</audio>
<span class="soundBtn3 clicked3">再生・停止</span>
<audio id="overSound3" preload="auto">
<source src="3.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
  ※お使いの環境では再生できません。
</audio>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
$(function(){
  $(".soundBtn1").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("clicked1")){
      $(this).removeClass("clicked1");
      document.getElementById("overSound1").currentTime = 0;
      document.getElementById("overSound1").play();
    }else{
      $(this).addClass("clicked1");
      document.getElementById("overSound1").pause();
    }
  });
});

$(function(){
  $(".soundBtn2").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("clicked2")){
      $(this).removeClass("clicked2");
      document.getElementById("overSound2").currentTime = 0;
      document.getElementById("overSound2").play();
    }else{
      $(this).addClass("clicked2");
      document.getElementById("overSound2").pause();
    }
  });
});

$(function(){
  $(".soundBtn3").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("clicked3")){
      $(this).removeClass("clicked3");
      document.getElementById("overSound3").currentTime = 0;
      document.getElementById("overSound3").play();
    }else{
      $(this).addClass("clicked3");
      document.getElementById("overSound3").pause();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: 問題を再現するための HTML を質問文へ追記していただけませんか？

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/218844

Comment: **$(".soundBtn1").click**
の"else"条件の処理を入れるのでは駄目ということでしょうか？

Comment: supaさん　HTML追加しました。

Comment: wakuwakuさん　https://lab.studio-benkei.com/jquery-audio/　のサイトを参考にした為、$(".soundBtn1").click をどの様に追加したら良いか分からず悩んでいるのですが、教えて頂けますでしょうか？　javascript初心者ですいません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ボタンが押されたら、まずは全ての音を止めてしまえばよいでしょう。

```js
$(".soundBtn1").click(function(){
  $("#overSound1")[0].pause(); // 追加
  $("#overSound2")[0].pause(); // 追加
  $("#overSound3")[0].pause(); // 追加
  if ($(this).hasClass("clicked1")) {
    $(this).removeClass("clicked1");
    document.getElementById("overSound1").currentTime = 0;
    document.getElementById("overSound1").play();
  } else {
    $(this).addClass("clicked1");
  }
});
```

`.soundBtn2` と `.soundBtn3` のクリックハンドラでも同様に`pause()`を追加します。

Comment: int32_tさん　コードありがとうございました。実装できました。

Comment: @sayo  解決しましたら、この回答に「承認済み」マークを付けてくださいませ。

Comment: int32_tさん　初めての投稿で、使い方が分からず、すいません。「承認済み」マーク　緑のチェックをクリックしたのですがこれで宜しいのでしょうか？

Comment: @sayo バッチリです! ありがとうございます。